Why do we have to return the launch arguments at the end of the launch description in ros2 launch file?
If I understand correctly, we use the LaunchConfiguration function to define local variables in the launch file. To be able to set them externally, we have to use the DeclareLaunchArgument function. But why is it necessary to rerurn the object created via DeclareLaunchArgument at the end of the launch description in a ros2 python launch file?
